# Class not serializing to XML File

Tags: c#, xml, streamwriter, textwriter

The code below does not output a stream. Looks correct to me but doesn't work.

```
LineItem i1 = new LineItem() { Id = 1, PartNumber = "abc" };
LineItem i2 = new LineItem() { Id = 2, PartNumber = "def" };
LineItem i3 = new LineItem() { Id = 3, PartNumber = "ghi" };
LineItem i4 = new LineItem() { Id = 4, PartNumber = "jkl" };

List<LineItem> l1 = new List<LineItem>();
l1.Add(i1);
l1.Add(i2);
l1.Add(i3);
l1.Add(i4);

Customer c1 = new Customer() { Id = 1, Company = "MSFT", Name = "John", LineItems = l1 };

XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));
TextWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(@"XMLFile1.xml");
mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, c1);
myWriter.Close();
```

Comment: So, what _does_ it output?

Comment: First off, show the Customer class definition

Comment: Also, you should have a `using` block around the `TextWriter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Look at the inner exception that you are getting. It will tell you
  which field/property it is having trouble serializing.
- Also, remember that serialized classes must have default constructor.
  if you have a constructor with a parameter, you'll need to add the
  default one too. (having no constructors is fine)
- XmlSerializer won't serialize abstract properties, take that into account